# VSTO Office Add In gives exception when opening MessageBox

Tags: c#, .net, vsto

I have an MS Office Word add-in implemented in .Net C#.
In a particular case when I try to open a message box

```
MessageBox.Show()
```

I get an exception

```
System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException
```

which apparantly has nothing to do with the MessageBox.

The flow is as such

```
 1- Perform call to MessageBox.Show() -> All goes well
 2- Perform some WCF calls -> All goes well
 3- Perform a new call to MessageBox.Show() -> I get the exception
```

The exception is

```
System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException: Type is not resolved for member XXX
```

where XXX is an implementation of

```
System.Security.Principal.IPrincipal
```

Is there anyone who has an idea of what I might be doing wrong.
If I skip step 2, then step 3 works fine too.
If I skip step 1 (the first MessageBox show) and only perform steps 2 and 3 then it works fine too.

Comment: can you share your third messagebox.show code .

Comment: return MessageBox.Show(message, title, buttons, icon, defaultButton);

Comment: where message and title are strings and  buttons = MessageBoxButtons.OK, icon = MessageBoxIcon.Information, defaultButton = MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1

Comment: Are you able to reduce your code to something that can be posted here, that repros and that we can put into a project for testing? This is really much too little information...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem in the past.

Are you using custom Identity? If so, then please make sure that your Identity is [Serializable] and implements ISerializable interface. That will fix your issue.

[Reference](https://forums.asp.net/t/1469217.aspx?Custom+identity+problem+SerializationException+Type+is+not+resolved+for+member+)
(it's about server application, but the same applies if you're working with Office and call WCF).

Why that is need is beyond me though.

Comment: Thanks. That helped. What a strange error and behaviour though.